# Can't add Sentry to ASP.NET Core Web API project in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, sentry

I am trying to add Sentry to my ASP.NET Core Web API project using .NET 6. However, I am encountering an issue where I cannot find the `AddSentry` method in `IServiceCollection`, even though I have installed the `Sentry.AspNetCore` package.

I have followed the instructions on the Sentry documentation and added the `SentryAspNetCore` package to my project. I also added the following line to my Program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddSentry();
```

However, I get the following error when building my project:

> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddSentry' and the best extension method overload 'LoggingBuilderExtensions.AddSentry(ILoggingBuilder, string)' requires a receiver of type 'ILoggingBuilder'

It seems that `AddSentry` is not recognized as an extension method of `IServiceCollection`. I have searched for similar issues and found some suggestions to add the `Sentry.Extensions.Logging` package, but that did not help.

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong and how I can add Sentry to my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

To get not just logging but Middleware and  error page, use the `UseSentry` extension method on the WebHostBuilder

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Call UseSentry on the web host.
builder.WebHost.UseSentry();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRouting();


// You'll also likely want this, to capture transactions.
// This must be *after* UseRouting.
app.UseSentryTracing();
```

Docs: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/aspnetcore/